# Adding an html element around text that does not affect the page (for tooltip)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a tooltip plugin here:
http://shawntabrizi.com/cryptip/

Source here: https://github.com/shawntabrizi/cryptip/blob/master/webextension/content.js

The basics here is that I use [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) to add a tooltip around certain matching text to display price information.

To do this, I look through the HTML body, find any text nodes, and then search that text node for the matching text. If I find matching text, I modify the text to include a `<span>` with a certain class in order to trigger Tippy.js.

Here is the relevant code:

```
if (node.nodeType === 3) {
    var text = node.nodeValue;

    if (reCoins.test(text)) {
        text = text.replace(reCoins, function (a, b) {
            console.info('Adding cryptip to:' + b, element.tagName)
            let priceString = createPriceString(coindict, b, currency, time);
            return `<span class="cryptip" title="${priceString}">${b}</span>`;
        });

        var replacementNode = document.createElement('span');
        replacementNode.innerHTML = text;
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(replacementNode, node);
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
    }
}
```

However, I have received reports that on some pages, the span element is picking up styling which affects the rendering of the page. One example of a page is https://yout.com/ which has a default styling on span elements nested in certain areas creating a problem like this:

[image: example of the problem]

I tried a solution where I set the CSS on the element to be:

```
.cryptip {
    all: unset;
}
```

However, the page seems to be loading other styles on top of it:

[image]

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is there some CSS trick I can do to avoid my element being styled? Maybe create a CSS styling with every possible style element for a span, and set it to default with the `!important` attribute.
2. Is there another 'psudo' element in HTML that I can use which does not affect the page rendering? Something like `<foo class="cryptip"></foo>` should work for getting tippy on the page, but does there exist such an element?

Comment: If you use an HTML Tag declaration that isn't recognized the node is created as an HTMLUnknownElement, which doesn't have its own properties and methods, but acts as a pass-through to inherit everything from HTMLElement. There is no designated pseudo element because any unassigned tag can be used, though if you _can_ style the specific tag instead of creating an unknown element that would obviously be preferred for posterity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I am understanding you correctly, I can make up a tag name, and HTML will still be valid, and treat the tag as an unknown element. Unfortunately I cannot style the existing tag that contains the text, because the tag may contain more than the word that I want to trigger a tooltip. Therefore a new element must be created around that specific word/words.

Comment: @zfrisch, I tried it out and it seems to work great :) Are there any catches to doing this? It appears all browsers support the [unknown element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement), but I just want to make sure. Also, can I use JS to now query for these kinds of elements by tag name? `document.getElementsByTagName('foo')`?

Comment: Yes you can search by tag name. It's setup like other elements, for instance a `section` tag is directly inherited from an `HTMLElement`, and you can think of the unknown tag similarly since all it has between it and the `HTMLElement` prototype is an empty object. It's also worth noting that there is a customElements spec being looked at by the w3c but its support is sparse https://caniuse.com/#search=Custom%20Elements . There aren't any real drawbacks I'm aware of with using an unknown tag except maintainability and there's no guarantee it will always work since Browsers are fickle.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer. If you want to write it up below, I will be happy to give you some internet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an HTML Tag declaration that isn't recognized the node is created from an `HTMLUnknownElement` prototype, which doesn't have its own properties and methods, but acts as a pass-through to inherit everything from `HTMLElement`. `HTMLElement` is the prototype that offers your most base element methods and properties such as `offsetHeight` and `style`

You can imagine then that there is no designated pseudo element because *any* unassigned tag can be used, though if you can style the specific tag you're looking to replace instead that would obviously be preferred for posterity.

If you have to, in your current use case, use an unassigned tag, because of it's prototype it is setup like other elements and you will be able to search for it in the DOM. A `section` tag is directly inherited from the `HTMLElement` prototype, and you can think of the unknown tag similarly since all it has between it and the HTMLElement prototype is an empty object. It's also worth noting that there is a [customElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) spec being looked at by the w3c but its support [is sparse](http://caniuse.com/#search=Custom%20Elements).

To summarize there aren't any real drawbacks currently that I'm aware of except maintainability of the codebase(you're going to want to be sure to document well that you are adding a tag) and you may have to be prepared to change it if, for instance, in the future Custom Elements require a declaration - and always keep in mind that there's no guarantee it will always work as well as it does now since there is no spec on the issue and Browsers are fickle.